# Detecting bpm of audio input using javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio, p5.js

I'm trying to put together an audio input + beatdetektor example so I could calculate the BPM of a track playing through my line in ( or even microphone input ).

Unfortunately, I didn't understand exactly how the "time" parameter from the "process" method is supposed to be used ( specially in that case, where I don't necessarily know when the track changes, etc ).

Here is some code I put together trying to solve this puzzle using the lovely p5.js library, please let me know how I could tweak this to achieve the desired effect.

```
<script src="js/p5-zip/p5.js"></script>
<script src="js/p5-zip/addons/p5.sound.js"></script>

<script src="js/beatdetektor-master/beatdetektor.js"></script>

<script>

  // beatdetektor stuff

  bd_med = new BeatDetektor(85,169);

  vu = new BeatDetektor.modules.vis.VU();
  kick_det = new BeatDetektor.modules.vis.BassKick();

  // p5 stuff
  mic = new p5.AudioIn();
  mic.start();
  fft = new p5.FFT();
  fft.setInput(mic);

  funk = function(){
    spectrum = fft.analyze();

    bd_med.process( (new Date).getTime(), spectrum)
  }

  // analyse with 60 frames, we could maybe use requestAnimationFrame here
  setInterval( funk, 1000/60 )

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation on the BeatDetektor library](https://github.com/cjcliffe/beatdetektor/blob/master/js/beatdetektor.js), the `process()` function takes an argument in **seconds**.

My guess would be that the argument is the seconds since the start of the song, not an absolute date. Right now you're passing in the number of milliseconds since 1970. I don't know of any songs that are that long.

[Here](https://github.com/cjcliffe/beatdetektor/blob/master/js/test/test.html) is an example of using the `process()` function to simulate 30 seconds of a song.

It looks like you're going to have to keep track of the start time of the song, then calculate how much time has passed when calling the `process()` function. Processing has a handy [`millis()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/millis) function that might help you out.