# JS - Bpm Analyzer: Argument of AudioContext.decodeAudioData can't be a detached buffer

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm working on an audio analysis project and I was looking for a way to get the bpm from an mp3 / wav audio using JavaScript.

This is the only post about it that I found: [Detecting bpm of audio input using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38029623/detecting-bpm-of-audio-input-using-javascript)

This is the only solution I found:

```
(function() {
  var AUDIO_URL = 'media/song.mp3';
  var CHANNELS, NUMBER_OF_PREVIOUS_SAMPLES, SAMPLES_PER_INSTANT_ENERGY, SAMPLE_RATE, THRESHOLD_CONSTANT, VARIANCE_COEFFICIENT, audioContext; 
  var audioSample, beatDetector, beatDetectorVisualisation, beatVisualisation, getAudioContext, getOfflineAudioContext, loadAudioFromUrl, main; 
  var playTrack, sampleLengthSeconds, timeline, trackStartTime, updateAudioFromArrayBuffer, updateAudioFromPcmData, updateBeats, updateSongPlace;
  var updateVisualisation, windowEnd, windowStart,
    __extends = function(child, parent) { 
        for (var key in parent) { 
            if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; 
            } function ctor() { 
                this.constructor = child; 
                } 
                ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; 
                child.prototype = new ctor(); 
                child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; 
                },
    __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty;

  THRESHOLD_CONSTANT = 1.5;
  VARIANCE_COEFFICIENT = 0;
  SAMPLES_PER_INSTANT_ENERGY = 1024;
  NUMBER_OF_PREVIOUS_SAMPLES = 43;
  CHANNELS = 1;
  SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
  audioContext = null;
  audioSample = null;
  sampleLengthSeconds = 0;
  trackStartTime = 0;
  beatVisualisation = null;
  beatDetectorVisualisation = null;
  beatDetector = null;
  windowStart = 0;
  windowEnd = null;
  timeline = null;

  getAudioContext = function() {
    var AudioContext;
    AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    if (audioContext == null) {
      audioContext = new AudioContext();
    }
    return audioContext;
  };

  getOfflineAudioContext = function(channels, length, sampleRate) {
    var OfflineAudioContext;
    OfflineAudioContext = window.OfflineAudioContext || window.webkitOfflineAudioContext;
    return new OfflineAudioContext(channels, length, sampleRate);
  };

  this.SoundEnergyBeatDetector = (function() {
    var BEAT_MIN_DISTANCE_SAMPLES, IMPULSE_TRAIN_SIZE, MAX_DISTANCE_MULTIPLIER, MAX_SEARCH_WINDOW_SIZE;

    SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
    BEAT_MIN_DISTANCE_SAMPLES = 10;
    MAX_DISTANCE_MULTIPLIER = 2;
    IMPULSE_TRAIN_SIZE = 108;
    MAX_SEARCH_WINDOW_SIZE = 2;

    function SoundEnergyBeatDetector() {}

    SoundEnergyBeatDetector.prototype.detectBeats = function(
        pcmAudioData, previousEnergyVarianceCoefficient, previousAverageEnergyCoefficient, samplesPerInstantEnergy, numberOfPreviousEnergies) {
      var c, currentIndex, currentTimeSeconds, distanceBetweenBeatIndexes, distanceInEnergyIndexBetweenBeats, i, instantEnergySum, lastBeatIndex;
      var maxCountIndex, meanCount, pcm, previousEnergies, previousEnergiesAverage, previousEnergiesIndex, previousEnergiesSum, previousEnergiesVariance;
      var previousEnergy, sumOfDifferencesFromAverage, threshold, v, _i, _j, _k, _len, _len1, _len2, _ref;
      this.maximumEnergies = [];
      distanceInEnergyIndexBetweenBeats = [];
      lastBeatIndex = 0;
      this.energies = [];
      this.averageEnergies = [];
      this.maxEnergy = 0;
      previousEnergies = [];
      previousEnergiesIndex = 0;
      instantEnergySum = 0;
      for (i = _i = 0, _len = pcmAudioData.length; _i < _len; i = ++_i) {
        pcm = pcmAudioData[i];
        instantEnergySum += Math.pow(pcm, 2);
        if (i % samplesPerInstantEnergy !== 0) {
          continue;
        }
        if (instantEnergySum > this.maxEnergy) {
          this.maxEnergy = instantEnergySum;
        }
        currentTimeSeconds = i / SAMPLE_RATE;
        this.energies.push([currentTimeSeconds, instantEnergySum]);
        if (previousEnergies.length < numberOfPreviousEnergies) {
          previousEnergies.push(instantEnergySum);
        } else {
          previousEnergiesSum = 0;
          for (_j = 0, _len1 = previousEnergies.length; _j < _len1; _j++) {
            previousEnergy = previousEnergies[_j];
            previousEnergiesSum += previousEnergy;
          }
          previousEnergiesAverage = previousEnergiesSum / numberOfPreviousEnergies;
          sumOfDifferencesFromAverage = 0;
          for (_k = 0, _len2 = previousEnergies.length; _k < _len2; _k++) {
            previousEnergy = previousEnergies[_k];
            sumOfDifferencesFromAverage += Math.pow(previousEnergy - previousEnergiesAverage, 2);
          }
          previousEnergiesVariance = sumOfDifferencesFromAverage / numberOfPreviousEnergies;
          v = previousEnergiesVariance * previousEnergyVarianceCoefficient;
          c = v + parseFloat(previousAverageEnergyCoefficient);
          threshold = c * previousEnergiesAverage;
          this.averageEnergies.push([currentTimeSeconds, threshold]);
          if (instantEnergySum > threshold) {
            currentIndex = this.averageEnergies.length - 1;
            distanceBetweenBeatIndexes = currentIndex - lastBeatIndex;
            if (distanceBetweenBeatIndexes > BEAT_MIN_DISTANCE_SAMPLES) {
              lastBeatIndex = currentIndex;
              this.maximumEnergies.push(currentTimeSeconds);
              distanceInEnergyIndexBetweenBeats.push(distanceBetweenBeatIndexes);
            }
          }
          previousEnergies.splice(previousEnergiesIndex, 1, instantEnergySum);
        }
        previousEnergiesIndex++;
        if (previousEnergiesIndex >= numberOfPreviousEnergies) {
          previousEnergiesIndex = 0;
        }
        instantEnergySum = 0;
      }
      _ref = this._calculateTempo(distanceInEnergyIndexBetweenBeats, numberOfPreviousEnergies, samplesPerInstantEnergy), meanCount = _ref[0], maxCountIndex = _ref[1];
      return this._calculateConvolution(meanCount, maxCountIndex);
    };

    SoundEnergyBeatDetector.prototype._calculateTempo = function(distanceInEnergyIndexBetweenBeats, numberOfPreviousEnergies, samplesPerInstantEnergy) {
      var a, b, beatDistanceCount, beatDistanceCounts, distance, divisor, i, maxCountIndex, maxCountSoFar, maxDistanceBetwenBeats, meanCount, neighbourCount, neighbourIndex, _i, _j, _k, _len, _len1;
      maxDistanceBetwenBeats = numberOfPreviousEnergies * MAX_DISTANCE_MULTIPLIER;
      beatDistanceCounts = [];
      for (i = _i = 0; 0 <= maxDistanceBetwenBeats ? _i <= maxDistanceBetwenBeats : _i >= maxDistanceBetwenBeats; i = 0 <= maxDistanceBetwenBeats ? ++_i : --_i) {
        beatDistanceCounts.push(0);
      }
      for (_j = 0, _len = distanceInEnergyIndexBetweenBeats.length; _j < _len; _j++) {
        distance = distanceInEnergyIndexBetweenBeats[_j];
        if (distance < maxDistanceBetwenBeats) {
          beatDistanceCounts[distance]++;
        }
      }
      maxCountIndex = 0;
      maxCountSoFar = 0;
      for (i = _k = 0, _len1 = beatDistanceCounts.length; _k < _len1; i = ++_k) {
        beatDistanceCount = beatDistanceCounts[i];
        if (beatDistanceCount > maxCountSoFar) {
          maxCountSoFar = beatDistanceCount;
          maxCountIndex = i;
        }
      }
      if (maxCountIndex === beatDistanceCounts.length - 1) {
        neighbourIndex = maxCountIndex - 1;
      } else if (maxCountIndex === 0) {
        neighbourIndex = maxCountIndex + 1;
      } else {
        a = maxCountIndex - 1;
        b = maxCountIndex + 1;
        if (beatDistanceCounts[a] > beatDistanceCounts[b]) {
          neighbourIndex = a;
        } else {
          neighbourIndex = b;
        }
      }
      neighbourCount = beatDistanceCounts[neighbourIndex];
      divisor = maxCountSoFar + neighbourCount;
      if (divisor === 0) {
        meanCount = 0;
      } else {
        meanCount = (maxCountIndex * maxCountSoFar + neighbourIndex * neighbourCount) / divisor;
      }
      this.bpm = 60 / (meanCount * (samplesPerInstantEnergy / SAMPLE_RATE));
      return [meanCount, maxCountIndex];
    };

    SoundEnergyBeatDetector.prototype._calculateConvolution = function(meanCount, maxCountIndex) {
      var b, beatsConvolution, conv, currentConv, espace, i, impulseTrain, j, localMaxPosition, maxConv, maxConvIndex, offsetIndexLeft, offsetIndexRight, ratio, searchForMaxInWindow, _i, _j, _k, _l, _len, _len1, _m, _ref, _ref1, _results;
      impulseTrain = [];
      espace = 0;
      impulseTrain.push(1);
      for (i = _i = 1; 1 <= IMPULSE_TRAIN_SIZE ? _i <= IMPULSE_TRAIN_SIZE : _i >= IMPULSE_TRAIN_SIZE; i = 1 <= IMPULSE_TRAIN_SIZE ? ++_i : --_i) {
        if (espace >= meanCount) {
          impulseTrain.push(1);
          espace -= meanCount;
        } else {
          impulseTrain.push(0);
        }
        espace += 1;
      }
      beatsConvolution = [];
      this.convolution = [];
      maxConv = 0;
      maxConvIndex = 0;
      for (i = _j = 0, _ref = this.averageEnergies.length - IMPULSE_TRAIN_SIZE - 1; 0 <= _ref ? _j <= _ref : _j >= _ref; i = 0 <= _ref ? ++_j : --_j) {
        beatsConvolution[i] = 0;
        this.convolution[i] = [this.averageEnergies[i][0], 0];
        for (j = _k = 0; 0 <= IMPULSE_TRAIN_SIZE ? _k <= IMPULSE_TRAIN_SIZE : _k >= IMPULSE_TRAIN_SIZE; j = 0 <= IMPULSE_TRAIN_SIZE ? ++_k : --_k) {
          this.convolution[i][1] += this.averageEnergies[i + j][1] * impulseTrain[j];
        }
        currentConv = Math.abs(this.convolution[i][1]);
        if (currentConv > maxConv) {
          maxConv = currentConv;
          maxConvIndex = i;
        }
      }
      ratio = 1 / maxConv;
      _ref1 = this.convolution;
      for (_l = 0, _len = _ref1.length; _l < _len; _l++) {
        conv = _ref1[_l];
        conv[1] *= ratio;
      }
      searchForMaxInWindow = (function(_this) {
        return function(offset) {
          var maxIndex, maxSoFar, _m, _ref2, _ref3;
          maxSoFar = 0;
          maxIndex = offset;
          for (i = _m = _ref2 = offset - MAX_SEARCH_WINDOW_SIZE, _ref3 = offset + MAX_SEARCH_WINDOW_SIZE; _ref2 <= _ref3 ? _m <= _ref3 : _m >= _ref3; i = _ref2 <= _ref3 ? ++_m : --_m) {
            if (i < 0) {
              continue;
            }
            if (i >= _this.convolution.length) {
              break;
            }
            conv = _this.convolution[i][1];
            if (conv > maxSoFar) {
              maxSoFar = conv;
              maxIndex = i;
            }
          }
          return maxIndex;
        };
      })(this);
      beatsConvolution[maxConvIndex] = 1;
      offsetIndexRight = maxConvIndex + maxCountIndex;
      while (offsetIndexRight < this.convolution.length && this.convolution[offsetIndexRight][1] > 0) {
        localMaxPosition = searchForMaxInWindow(offsetIndexRight);
        beatsConvolution[localMaxPosition] = 1;
        offsetIndexRight = localMaxPosition + maxCountIndex;
      }
      offsetIndexLeft = maxConvIndex - maxCountIndex;
      while (offsetIndexLeft > 0) {
        localMaxPosition = searchForMaxInWindow(offsetIndexLeft);
        beatsConvolution[localMaxPosition] = 1;
        offsetIndexLeft = localMaxPosition - maxCountIndex;
      }
      this.beats = [];
      _results = [];
      for (i = _m = 0, _len1 = beatsConvolution.length; _m < _len1; i = ++_m) {
        b = beatsConvolution[i];
        if (b > 0) {
          _results.push(this.beats.push(this.convolution[i][0]));
        } else {
          _results.push(void 0);
        }
      }
      return _results;
    };

    return SoundEnergyBeatDetector;

  })();


  loadAudioFromUrl = function(url, callback) {
    var request;
    request = new XMLHttpRequest;
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    request.onload = function() {
      return callback(request.response);
    };
    return request.send();
  };

  this.AbstractAudioSample = (function() {
    function AbstractAudioSample() {
      this.playing = false;
    }

    AbstractAudioSample.prototype.loadAudio = function() {
      throw 'Load Audio must be implemented by subclass';
    };

    AbstractAudioSample.prototype.tryPlay = function(offset, gain) {
      var gainNode;
      if (this.buffer == null) {
        return;
      }
      this.source = this._ctx.createBufferSource();
      this.source.buffer = this.buffer;
      gainNode = this._ctx.createGain();
      if (gain != null) {
        gainNode.gain.value = gain;
      }
      this.source.connect(gainNode);
      gainNode.connect(this._ctx.destination);
      if ($.isNumeric(offset)) {
        this.source.start(0, offset);
      } else {
        this.source.start(0);
      }
      return this.playing = true;
    };

    AbstractAudioSample.prototype.stop = function() {
      if (this.source == null) {
        return;
      }
      this.source.stop(0);
      return this.playing = false;
    };

    return AbstractAudioSample;

  })();

  this.ArrayBufferAudioSample = (function(_super) {
    __extends(ArrayBufferAudioSample, _super);

    function ArrayBufferAudioSample(_at_arrayBuffer) {
      this.arrayBuffer = _at_arrayBuffer;
      ArrayBufferAudioSample.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    ArrayBufferAudioSample.prototype.loadAudio = function(_at__ctx, callback) {
      this._ctx = _at__ctx;
      return this._ctx.decodeAudioData(this.arrayBuffer, (function(_this) {
        return function(buffer) {
          _this.buffer = buffer;
          if (callback != null) {
            return callback(_this);
          }
        };
      })(this));
    };

    return ArrayBufferAudioSample;

  })(AbstractAudioSample);

  this.PcmAudioGenerator = (function() {
    function PcmAudioGenerator() {}

    PcmAudioGenerator.prototype.getPcmAudioData = function(offlineContext, audioSample, callback) {
      var renderAudioSampleOffline;
      renderAudioSampleOffline = (function(_this) {
        return function(audioSample) {
          offlineContext.oncomplete = function(event) {
            return callback(event.renderedBuffer.getChannelData(0));
          };
          audioSample.tryPlay();
          return offlineContext.startRendering();
        };
      })(this);
      return audioSample.loadAudio(offlineContext, renderAudioSampleOffline);
    };

    return PcmAudioGenerator;

  })();

  updateSongPlace = function(fractionThroughSong) {
    if (audioSample.playing) {
      audioSample.stop();
    }
    trackStartTime = windowStart + ((windowEnd - windowStart) * fractionThroughSong);
    return timeline.render(trackStartTime, windowStart, windowEnd);
  };

  updateVisualisation = function() {
    beatDetectorVisualisation.render(beatDetector, windowStart, windowEnd);
    return timeline.render(trackStartTime, windowStart, windowEnd);
  };

  updateBeats = function(pcmAudioData) {
    var nOPS, pAEC, pEVC, sPIE;
    pAEC = THRESHOLD_CONSTANT;
    pEVC = VARIANCE_COEFFICIENT;
    sPIE = SAMPLES_PER_INSTANT_ENERGY;
    nOPS = NUMBER_OF_PREVIOUS_SAMPLES;
    beatDetector = new SoundEnergyBeatDetector();
    beatDetector.detectBeats(pcmAudioData, pEVC, pAEC, sPIE, nOPS);
    if (windowEnd == null) {
      windowEnd = sampleLengthSeconds;
    }
    console.log("bpm is " + beatDetector.bpm);
    $('#bpm').text((beatDetector.bpm.toFixed(2)) + "bpm");
    return updateVisualisation();
  };

  updateAudioFromPcmData = function(pcmAudioData) {
    var waveformVisualisation;
    waveformVisualisation = new WaveformVisualisation('#waveform', pcmAudioData);
    waveformVisualisation.render();
    return updateBeats(pcmAudioData);
  };

  updateAudioFromArrayBuffer = function(arrayBuffer) {
    audioContext = getAudioContext();
    audioSample = new ArrayBufferAudioSample(arrayBuffer);
    return audioSample.loadAudio(audioContext, function(audioSample) {
      var length, offlineAudioContext, pcmAudioGenerator, pcmAudioSample;
      pcmAudioSample = new ArrayBufferAudioSample(arrayBuffer);
      length = audioSample.buffer.length;
      sampleLengthSeconds = length / SAMPLE_RATE;
      offlineAudioContext = getOfflineAudioContext(CHANNELS, length, SAMPLE_RATE);
      pcmAudioGenerator = new PcmAudioGenerator();
      return pcmAudioGenerator.getPcmAudioData(offlineAudioContext, pcmAudioSample, updateAudioFromPcmData);
    });
  };


}).call(this);
```

---

I get the following error:

> Argument of AudioContext.decodeAudioData can't be a detached buffer

in line:

```
return this._ctx.decodeAudioData(this.arrayBuffer, (function(_this) {
```

---

I tried to shorten down the code as much as possible without removing important information, but please feel free to edit it.

Comment: There seem to be [plenty of questions about `decodeAudioData`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=decodeAudioData+%5Bweb-audio-api%5D).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't use the same `ArrayBuffer` twice with `decodeAudioData()`. You can think of this as if `decodeAudioData()` would consume the `ArrayBuffer` which means it is gone afterwards. What really happens is that the `ArrayBuffer` is transferred to another thread by the Web Audio API behind the scenes.

An easy fix would be to copy the `ArrayBuffer` before you decode it.

```
new ArrayBufferAudioSample(arrayBuffer.slice(0));
```

By the way, I've created a simple beat detector called [web-audio-beat-detector](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/web-audio-beat-detector). Maybe that works for you. Otherwise there is also [essentia.js](https://github.com/MTG/essentia.js) which has a much more elaborate beat detection.

Comment: Thank you very much